# new Date() funciona en chrome pero no en Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Estoy creando una fecha a partir de un string

```
var fechaStr = "28-11-2017";
var fechaDt = new Date(fechaStr);
```

Pero al creal la variable `fechaDt` y utilizarla arroja el mensaje:

> variable fechaDt undefinied

En chrome funciona sin problemas, pero al utilizarla en firefox da ese mensaje.

Comment: Tal y como te comentan, debes respetar los constructores para poder generar el obj Date. Si te interesa poder indicarle el formato, te recomiendo la libreria [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) que extiende la clase Date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según ECMA Script, cuando creas una nueva instancia de `Date` pasándole un valor:

```
new Date (value)
```

Ocurre lo siguiente:

> The [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of the newly constructed
>   object is set as follows:
>
> 1. Let v be ToPrimitive(value).
> 2. If Type(v) is String, then
>
>    a. Parse v as a date, in exactly the same manner as for the parse
>      method (15.9.4.2); let V be the time value for this date.
> 3. Else, let V be ToNumber(v).
> 4. Set the [[PrimitiveValue]] internal property of the newly constructed object to TimeClip(V) and return.
>
> <sub>[ECMA Script 15.9.3.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2)</sub>

En tu caso **(2)**, como el parámetro es una cadena, se procede a convertir dicha cadena en una fecha válida, mediante el método `Date.parse (string)`.

Este método dice que aplica unas reglas muy precisas para hacer la conversión, y que si hay fechas irreconocibles retornará `NaN` (Not a Number). Significa que si tu fecha no está en un formato válido, será un valor nulo:

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String
>   according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format
>   (15.9.1.15). If the String does not conform to that format the
>   function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or
>   implementation-specific date formats. Unrecognisable Strings or dates
>   containing illegal element values in the format String shall cause
>   Date.parse to return NaN.
>
> <sub>[ECMA Script 15.9.4.2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2)</sub>

Las reglas que se aplican para convertir tu String en fecha, vienen especificadas en el apartado 15.9.1.15 de ECMA Script:

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based
>   upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 Extended Format. The format is
>   as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`
>
> Where the fields are as follows:
>
> `YYYY`: is the decimal digits of the year 0000 to 9999 in the
>   Gregorian calendar.
>
> `-`   “-” (hyphen) appears literally twice in the string.
>
> `MM`  is the month of the year from 01 (January) to 12 (December).
>
> `DD`  is the day of the month from 01 to 31.
>
> `T`   “T” appears literally in the string, to indicate the beginning of
>   the time element.
>
> `HH`  is the number of complete hours that have passed since midnight
>   as two decimal digits from 00 to 24.
>
> `:`   “:” (colon) appears literally twice in the string.
>
> `mm`  is the number of complete minutes since the start of the hour as
>   two decimal digits from 00 to 59.
>
> `ss`  is the number of complete seconds since the start of the minute
>   as two decimal digits from 00 to 59.
>
> `.`   “.” (dot) appears literally in the string.
>
> `sss` is the number of complete milliseconds since the start of the
>   second as three decimal digits.
>
> `Z`   is the time zone offset specified as “Z” (for UTC) or either “+”
>   or “-” followed by a time expression HH:mm
>
> This format includes date-only forms:
>
> `YYYY`
>
> `YYYY-MM`
>
> `YYYY-MM-DD`
>
> It also includes “date-time” forms that consist of one of the above
>   date-only forms immediately followed by one of the following time
>   forms with an optional time zone offset appended:
>
> `THH:mm`
>
> `THH:mm:ss`
>
> `THH:mm:ss.sss`
>
> All numbers must be base 10. If the MM or DD fields are absent “01” is
>   used as the value. If the HH, mm, or ss fields are absent “00” is used
>   as the value and the value of an absent sss field is “000”. The value
>   of an absent time zone offset is “Z”.
>
> Illegal values (out-of-bounds as well as syntax errors) in a format
>   string means that the format string is not a valid instance of this
>   format.
>
> NOTE 1 As every day both starts and ends with midnight, the two
>   notations 00:00 and 24:00 are available to distinguish the two
>   midnights that can be associated with one date. This means that the
>   following two notations refer to exactly the same point in time:
>   1995-02-04T24:00 and 1995-02-05T00:00
>
> NOTE 2 There exists no international standard that specifies
>   abbreviations for civil time zones like CET, EST, etc. and sometimes
>   the same abbreviation is even used for two very different time zones.
>   For this reason, ISO 8601 and this format specifies numeric
>   representations of date and time.
>
> <sub>[ECMA Script 15.9.1.15](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)</sub>

---

### Conclusión

Si vas a construir fechas pasando cadenas al constructor, estas deben cumplir con lo especificado en la sección **<kbd>15.9.1.15</kbd>** de ECMA Script indicada más arriba.

Si cambias tu fecha al formato `YYYY-MM-DD` o a cualquier otro de los indicados, se creará un objeto válido.

Por ejemplo:

```js
var fechaStr = "2017-11-28";
var fechaDt = new Date(fechaStr);
console.log(fechaDt);

var fechaDt = new Date(2017,11,28,24,00);
console.log(fechaDt);
```

Answer (score 2):

No puedes instanciar fechas como quieras. Por ejemplo:

```
new Date() // current date and time
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01
new Date(dateString)
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

o

```
d1 = new Date("October 13, 1975 11:13:00")
d2 = new Date(79,5,24)
d3 = new Date(79,5,24,11,33,0)
```

Este formato debería de funcionar en todos los navegadores:

```
new Date('2001-01-31 12:00:00')
Format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sss
Details: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15
```